# Error with auto_increment while conneted to Postgres via psql and puTTY

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment, identity, putty

I'm getting this error in puTTY. Not sure why, looks right to me ...

```
psql:pierre.sql:10: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
LINE 2:  c_id  INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                                ^
psql:pierre.sql:18: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
LINE 2:  r_id  INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,

--DROP TABLE customer, reservation;
CREATE TABLE customer(
    c_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    c_ref       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    f_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    l_name      VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address     VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    email       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE reservation(
    r_id        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    c_id        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL REFERENCES customer(c_id),
    book_date   DATE NOT NULL CHECK (book_date <= now()),
    s_time      DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    e_time      DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    amount      INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

[`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) looks like something you'd use with MySQL.

But, here, it seems you are using PostgreSQL.

According to the [**datatype `serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) section of the manual, postgresql's equivalent of `auto_increment` is **`serial`** or **`bigserial`**.

Quoting that page :

> The data types `serial` and `bigserial` are not true types, but merely
>   a notational convenience for setting up unique identifier columns
>   *(similar to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property supported by some other databases)*.

Answer (score 0):

In **Postgres 10** or later consider an **`IDENTITY`** column:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
    c_id        INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
```

(`PRIMARY KEY` also makes it `NOT NULL` automatically.)

Details:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

In **Postgres 9.6** or older consider a `serial` like [Pascal already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240270/939860).
Works in pg 10 or later, too, but `IDENTITY` is generally superior.