# Auto increment table column

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, auto-increment, database-table

Using Postgres, I'm trying to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` to number my primary key automatically in SQL. However, it gives me an error.

```
CREATE TABLE Staff   (
  ID        INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

The error:

> ```
> ********** Error **********
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "AUTO_INCREMENT"
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 63
> ```

Any idea why?

Comment: Which database do you use? "AUTO INCREMENT" exists only in a handful. In Oracle for example you need to create a `SEQUENCE`.

Comment: Use Serial:
[error-with-auto-increment-psql-putty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240250/error-with-auto-increment-psql-putty)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### Postgres 10 or later

Consider a standard-SQL **`IDENTITY`** column. [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) columns remain unchanged. (See below.) But the former is preferable in modern Postgres. Can be **`GENERATED BY DEFAULT`** or (stricter) **`GENERATED ALWAYS`**.
Basics in the [manual for `CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).
Details in this [blog entry by its principal author Peter Eisentraut.](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/)

#### *Create* table with `IDENTITY` column

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
  staff_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, staff    text NOT NULL
);
```

#### *Add* `IDENTITY` column to existing table

Table may or may not be populated with rows.

```
ALTER TABLE staff ADD COLUMN staff_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY;
```

To also make it the PK at the same time (table can't have a PK yet):

```
ALTER TABLE staff ADD COLUMN staff_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY;
```

See:

- [How to add a PostgreSQL 10 identity column to an existing table with rows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200156/3684)

#### *Replace* `serial` with `IDENTITY` column

See:

- [How to change a table ID from serial to identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232753/how-to-change-a-table-id-from-serial-to-identity/59233169#59233169)

You can override system values or user input in [**`INSERT`** commands with `OVERRIDING {SYSTEM|USER} VALUE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#id-1.9.3.152.6.2).

### Postgres 9.6 or older

(Still supported in newer versions, too.)
Use the [**`serial`** pseudo data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
  staff_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
, staff    text NOT NULL
);
```

It creates and attaches the sequence object automatically and sets the `DEFAULT` to `nextval()` from the sequence. It does all you need.

I use [legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in my examples. Makes your life with Postgres easier.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify which RDBMS you are using, however, in SQL Server you can use this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Staff]
(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL server database you can use `Identity(1,1)` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Staff
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**PostgreSQL: If you absolutely must have your own auto increment value:**

Then use a sequence:

```
ericlesc_schools=> drop table yar;
DROP TABLE
ericlesc_schools=> drop sequence user_id_seq;
DROP SEQUENCE
ericlesc_schools=> create sequence user_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE
ericlesc_schools=> create table yar(
                   id int default nextval('user_id_seq'), 
                   foobar varchar);
CREATE TABLE
ericlesc_schools=> insert into yar (foobar) values('hey alex');
INSERT 0 1
ericlesc_schools=> insert into yar (foobar) values('hey what derick');
INSERT 0 1
ericlesc_schools=> insert into yar (foobar) values('I look like a hushpuppy');
INSERT 0 1

ericlesc_schools=> select * from yar;
 id |     foobar      
----+-----------------
  1 | hey alex
  2 | hey what derick
  3 | I look like a hushpuppy
(3 rows)
```