# PostgreSQL Sequences across sessions

Tags: postgresql

If two clients **simultaneously** insert into a table that has a unique sequenced column, can one client get a `unique_violation`? In other words, can both clients get the same result from calling `nextval()` ?

I did a quick google search, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481448/currval-has-not-yet-been-defined-this-session-how-to-get-multi-session-sequence

Answer (score 4):

As is covered in detail in the PostgreSQL documentation for sequences:

- [`CREATE SEQUENCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html)
- [sequence manipulation functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)

no two `nextval` calls on the same sequence may ever return the same value, even in concurrent transactions. In other words two separate `nextval` calls for the same sequence can never return the same value. This results in some other anomalies, like "holes" in the sequence values appearing where a transaction rolls back, which are again described in the documentation.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko While well-intentioned that correction made the statement incorrect. I wrote it poorly and used a somewhat odd construction ("No two ... may ever"). You changed it to "No two ... may never" which doesn't make sense and is a double negative that could even be read as saying that they *can* get the same ID. The correct version would be "Two ... may never".