# How to increment ID for each INSERT?

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, auto-increment

In PostgreSQL I have table `comments` with primary key `comment_id` (`VARCHAR` of length 4). I have a form to insert a comment. How to get my Java Servlet to increment `comment_id` for each INSERT (0001 to 0002)?

Comment: If you want to stick with varchar, you realize that with a length of 4 you aren't going to be able to handle more than 10k comments, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use a VARCHAR for your id column. In postgres you can create a sequence and then get the next value of that sequence for each insert.

[here are the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createsequence.html)

Basically, you do something like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE mysequence START 101
```

Then, when you insert you do something like

```
INSERT INTO my_comment values (nextval('mysequence'), 'this is my comment');
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: in Postgres 10 or later, consider an **`IDENTITY`** column instead. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

---

Use the [**`serial`** pseudo data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) to begin with. It creates and attaches the sequence object automatically and sets the `DEFAULT` to `nextval()` from the sequence. It does all you need. Effective type for the column is `integer`. There is also `bigserial` and `smallserial` (in Postgres 9.2+). Just follow the link to the manual.

```sql
CREATE TABLE comments (
  comment_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, comment text NOT NULL
);
```

You can ignore the column for `INSERT` commands:

```
INSERT INTO my_comment (comment)
VALUES ('My comment here');
```

`comment_id` is filled in automatically.

But you should *always* provide a target column list for an `INSERT` command. If you later change table layout, your query may break in hurtful ways. It may be ok to skip the column list for ad-hoc commands or when the table structure is guaranteed (like when you created the table in the same line of code). Other than that, provide a column list!

If you want the resulting `comment_id` back, without another round trip to the server:

```
INSERT INTO my_comment (comment)
VALUES ('My comment here');
RETURNING comment_id;
```

Details in the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html).