# PostgreSQL autoincremented default value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increment value of a table ID for each INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635812/increment-value-of-a-table-id-for-each-insert)

I need to set DEFAULT VALUE on one table,

with structure:

```
column1    |     column2     |   column3
-----------+-----------------+-------------
10001      |      chair      |     23
10002      |      lamp       |     10
```

where If I

INSERT INTO column2 and column3 values (vase, 30), column1 will be autoincremented with value 10003 and each time with +1 value.

Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

You need:
1) Create a squence. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name -- sequence name
START 10003 -- value for the next row
```

2) Set `nextval('seq_name')` as default for column `column1`. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html).

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column1
SET DEFAULT nextval('seq_name');
```

UPD [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b0ab8/1) with example.

Comment: +1 - apparently you can do this in postgreSQL - DB2 (my version, at least) only allows constants or certain 'special registers', not sequences.  Although, conceptually, most people are probably going to expect an 'autogenerated' column, not as the 'default' value.