# DELETE in Postgres doesn't decrement serial PK?

Tags: postgresql, key, auto-increment

If in SQL Server we have a table with auto-increment, and 10 rows, and the last row has `id = 10`.
When you delete the last row, the next you insert will get the `id = 10` too, right?

But in Postgres, using `bigserial` as PK, when I delete the row with the max `id`, and insert a new row, it keeps incrementing more and more the pk number..

Is that right?

Comment: Even if you don't delete from the table there can still be gaps in the numbering. The ID is just that - an ID. It doesn't tell you anything about the order rows were inserted or committed in, or much else really.

Answer (score 5):

That's right.

[`bigserial` and `serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) are just notational convenience for creating a `bigint` / `integer` column with the default set to [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) from a connected sequence.

The underlying `SEQUENCE` is never decreased, serial numbers are never reused (without manual intervention). [Read the manual about sequences.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

It needs to be that way for safe concurrent use.

In Postgres 10 or later consider `IDENTITY` columns instead. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)