# Temporary sequence within a SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequences

I need to join two tables as part of a sql query, and whoever set up the database's `login` table did not include a column with a unique id for each login. I need to join `login` with a table where each login will line up with one or more rows of the other table, and I want to be able to uniquely identify each row from `login` without having to rely on the user id and the login timestamp being unique.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT l.*, pp.personpositionid
FROM (SELECT login.*, next_unique_bigint() AS loginid FROM login) l, personposition pp, personpositionstatus pps
WHERE l.personid = pp.personid
AND [...]
```

I could use random(), but I'd rather have the temporary unique "id's" be sequential (or even just predictable) rather than random. I've done a search for what I'm trying to do, but haven't found what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to do this in SQL, especially PostgreSQL? I'm guessing there is and I just don't know what keywords to search for.

Bonus points if you have a different way to keep the login records strait than giving each row a temporary id.

EDIT:
The overall purpose of this is to get a count of logins for a given date range. Each user has a set of Positions (roles? jobs?) that they hold from one point in time to another, and I need to count logins according to what position(s) the user held at the time they logged in. Each user can have 1 or more positions at any given time. They can only have 0 positions if their user account is deactivated, so naturally no logins will be recorded at a point in time when they have 0 positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you add a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) primary key column to the table?

```
ALTER TABLE login ADD column login_id serial;
ALTER TABLE login ADD CONSTRAINT login_pkey PRIMARY KEY(login_id);
```

The first operation will rewrite the table and take a lock for some time.
I would then run

```
VACCUM FULL ANALYZE login;
```

Inferior alternatives: `row_number()` as [pointed out by @Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311756/939860). For maximum performance you can leave the `OVER` clause empty:

```
row_number() OVER () AS rn
```

Aside: use the `AS` keyword for column aliases (while they are just noise for table aliases).

Or you can use the [**`ctid`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html) as poor man's surrogate for a primary key. That would be even *faster*:

Details:
[In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)

Example on dba.SE:
[numbering rows consecutively for a number of tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54960/numbering-rows-consecutively-for-a-number-of-tables/54992#54992)

Comment: All of these work, and this offers more than one solution, so you get the answer credit.

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use `ROW_NUMBER()`;

```
SELECT login.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY personid) rn
```

...for deterministic ordering or...

```
SELECT login.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () rn
```

...to just pick pseudo random (but sequential) numbers.

[A small SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d8f1/1).

Other alternatives are [ctid or oid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-system-columns.html), but they are PostgreSQL specific and both have some restrictions of their own (documented at the linked page)

Comment: This works but multiplies my query's runtime by 10 (~6 seconds vs ~0.6 seconds without `ROW_NUMBER()`). Does it matter what I do the OVER on? Any other ways I can optimize it?