# ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

Example data:

```
test,test2
----------
a,qwer
b,wert
c,erty
d,rtuy
d,tyui
e,yuio
e,uiop
```

I am trying to write a query which returns unique values in a table:

```
SELECT
  test

FROM aatest
GROUP BY test
HAVING (COUNT(test) = 1)
```

This works and returns a,b and c because d and e aren't unique.

But I want to print out test2 as well so I tried:

```
select 
test, 
test2
from aatest
GROUP BY test
HAVING (COUNT(test) = 1)
```

But I get the error.

Comment: Do we assume that the table does not have a primary key or any other combination of unique columns?

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the other column(s) in an aggregate function like `min()` or `max()`. Since there is only a single row per aggregate, it does not matter which:

```
SELECT test, min(test2) AS test2
FROM   aatest
GROUP  BY test
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

For lots of columns this is simpler:

```
SELECT t1.*  -- return all columns
FROM   aatest t1
LEFT   JOIN aatest t2 ON t2.test = t1.test AND t2.ctid <> t1.ctid
WHERE  t2.test IS NULL;
```

Assuming there is no PK or any other unique combination of columns we could use to unambiguously identify a row, I use the [internal (Postgres specific!) tuple ID `ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html). Related:

- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)

If `(test, test2)` is **unique**:

```
SELECT t1.*  -- return all columns
FROM   aatest t1
LEFT   JOIN aatest t2 ON t2.test = t1.test AND t2.test2 <> t1.test2
WHERE  t2.test IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Error message clearly explains the problem. The column list in select statement must be present in the group by unless u have an aggregate function(max,min,sum,count,etc..) on it  Try this, this is what you are trying to achieve

```
SELECT a.test,
       a.test2
FROM   aatest a
       JOIN (SELECT test
             FROM   aatest
             GROUP  BY test
             HAVING ( Count(test) = 1 )) b
         ON a.test = b.test
```

Comment: Use `USING (test)` or you have to table-qualify the ambiguous column name in the SELECT list: `a.test`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - Yes didn't check properly. Corrected now and thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM aatest
JOIN (
SELECT
  test
FROM aatest
GROUP BY test
HAVING (COUNT(test) = 1)
) T
on aatest.test = T.test
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you are grouping all repeated values in Test column, but if the values in Test2 are unique, where are they going to go? If the values in test two were numbers you could select them in the statement with an aggregate function such as count():

```
select 
test, 
count(test2)
from aatest
GROUP BY test
HAVING (COUNT(test) = 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the column **test2** in group by clause.
Are else use aggregate function for that particular column

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT(test)
FROM aatest
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function