# will select always start with the first (oldest) record in a table

Tags: postgresql

I made a table like

```
   record
----------+
1 | one   |
----------+
2 | two   |
----------+
3 | three |
----------+
4 | four  |
----------+
5 | five  |
----------+
```

There isn't an ID column, those are just the row numbers I see beside each row in DBVisualizer. I added the rows in the order 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Is this"

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sch.test_table limit 1;
```

certain always to get `one`, ie start with the "oldest" record? Or is will that change in large datasets?

Comment: It might be better to do it explicit by adding an `ORDER BY` to your query.

Comment: If you don't provide an `ORDER BY` clause, the server is free to return whatever row it wants to provide. If you're dependent on getting the most recent, add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Rows don't have any order. If you need a certain order you ***have*** to use an `order by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as per the SQL specification the order is indeterminate when not using `order by`. You're working with a set of data, and sets are not ordered. Also, the size of the set should not matter.

The [Postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) says:

> If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the
>   system finds fastest to produce.

Which means that the rows might come back in the expected order, or they might not - there are no guarantees.

The bottom line is that if you want deterministic results you have to use`order by`.

Comment: In this example, won't that give me an alphabetical listing? Is there no way to get them by order they were entered?

Comment: @thomas it would be alphabetical order yes. Without any other column to order by there is no stable way to get the order you want. Postgresql has some system specific thing that you might be able to abuse (see this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation).