# Deterministic sort order for window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, amazon-redshift

I've a `status` table and I want to fetch the latest details.

```
Slno |   ID | Status | date
  1  |   1  | Pass   | 15-06-2015 11:11:00 - this is inserted first
  2  |   1  | Fail   | 15-06-2015 11:11:00 - this is inserted second 
  3  |   2  | Fail   | 15-06-2015 12:11:11 - this is inserted first
  4  |   2  | Pass   | 15-06-2015 12:11:11 - this is inserted second
```

I use a window function with `partition by ID order by date desc` to fetch the first value.
Excepted Output :

```
2  |   1  | Fail   | 15-06-2015 11:11:00 - this is inserted second
4  |   2  | Pass   | 15-06-2015 12:11:11 - this is inserted second
```

Actual Output :

```
1  |   1  | Pass   | 15-06-2015 11:11:00 - this is inserted first
3  |   2  | Fail   | 15-06-2015 12:11:11 - this is inserted first
```

According to [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_order_by_WF.html], adding a second `ORDER BY` column to the window function may solve the problem. But I don't have any other column to differentiate the rows!
Is there another approach to solve the issue?

EDIT: I've added `slno` here for clarity. I don't have `slno` as such in the table!

My SQL:

```
with range as (
  select id from status where date between 01-06-2015 and 30-06-2015
), latest as ( 
  select status, id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) row_num
)
select * from latest where row_num = 1
```

Comment: What about your `Slno`* column ?

Comment: what agg function did you use?.. code please

Comment: With the data that you present (assuming `Slno` is just for presentation purposes here and not in your data) you cannot solve this because the `date` values for subsequent records are exactly the same (inserted during a single transaction?). You need to make sure that individual inserts take place in their own transaction or maybe call `pg_sleep(1)` after every insert to make sure they are at least a second apart.

Comment: Without any column to separate tied date apart you can't get the result you want.

Comment: The exact table definition would go a long way ...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `slno` in your table, then you don't have any reliable information which row was inserted first. There is no natural order in a table, the physical order of rows can change any time (with any update, or with `VACUUM`, etc.)

You *could* use an ***unreliable*** trick: order by the internal `ctid`.

```
select *
from  (
   select id, status
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id
                             ORDER BY date, ctid) AS row_num
   from   status  -- that's your table name??
   where  date >= '2015-06-01'  -- assuming column is actually a date
   and    date <  '2015-07-01'
  ) sub
where  row_num = 1;
```

- In absence of any other information which row came first (which is a **design error** to begin with, fix it!), you might try to save what you can using the internal [tuple ID `ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html)
- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)

Rows will be in physical order when inserted initially, but that can change any time with any write operation to the table or `VACUUM` or other events.
**This is a measure of last resort and it *will* break.**

- Your presented query was invalid on several counts: missing column name in 1st CTE, missing table name in 2nd CTE, ...
- You don't need a CTE for this.

Simpler with `DISTINCT ON` (considerations for `ctid` apply the same):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id, status
FROM   status
WHERE  date >= '2015-06-01'
AND    date <  '2015-07-01'
ORDER  BY id, date, ctid;
```

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)