# Dynamic pivot for thousands of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I'm using pgAdmin III / PostgreSQL 9.4 to store and work with my data. Sample of my current data:

```
x | y
--+--
0 | 1
1 | 1
2 | 1
5 | 2
5 | 2
2 | 2
4 | 3
6 | 3
2 | 3
```

How I'd like it to be formatted:

`1, 2, 3` -- column names are unique `y` values
`0, 5, 4` -- the first respective `x` values
`1, 5, 6` -- the second respective `x` values
`2, 2, 2` -- etc.

It would need to be dynamic because I have millions of rows and thousands of unique values for `y`.

Is using a dynamic pivot approach correct for this? I have not been able to successfully implement this:

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(y as varchar) + ']',
'[' + cast(y as varchar)+ ']')
FROM tableName
GROUP BY y

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '
SELECT x
FROM tableName
PIVOT
(
MAX(x)
FOR [y]
IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

It is stopping on the first line and giving the error:

> ```
> syntax error at or near "@"
> ```

All dynamic pivot examples I've seen use this, so I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

**Note: It is important for the `x` values to be stored in the correct order, as sequence matters. I can add another column to indicate sequential order if necessary.

Comment: First of all, did you try printing your `@query`? You might find something useful there and debug it.

Comment: Hi Evaldas, I get the same error when trying to print @query: syntax error at or near "@"

Comment: The problem is that the code is written for, and specific to, Microsoft SQL Server and as such won't work in Postgresql. There are ways to do this in Postgresql too though, as illustrated in this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087948/dynamic-pivot-query-using-postgresql-9-3

Comment: See this question too - it has a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query?lq=1

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm quite new to SQL and the source I was attempting from didn't specify SQL type being used. I will work from the other post and see what I can do.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand those posts at all--I'm going to try doing this in Python as a csv file instead. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The term "first row" assumes a natural order of rows, which does not exist in database tables. So, yes, you need to `add another column to indicate sequential order` like you suspected. I am assuming a column **`tbl_id`** for the purpose. Using the [`ctid`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66007/3684) would be a measure of last resort. See:

- [Deterministic sort order for window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31114882/deterministic-sort-order-for-window-functions/31117079#31117079)

The code you present looks like MS SQL Server code; invalid syntax for Postgres.

For `millions of rows and thousands of unique values for Y` it wouldn't even make sense to try and return individual columns. Postgres has generous limits, but not nearly generous enough for that. [According to the source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/de41869b64d57160f58852eab20a27f248188135/src/include/access/htup_details.h#L35-L47) or [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html), the absolute maximum number of columns is **1600**.

So we don't even get to discuss the restrictive characteristics of SQL, which demands to *know* columns and data types at execution time, not dynamically adjusted during execution. You would need **two separate calls**, like we discussed in great detail under this related question.

- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334)

Another answer by Clodoaldo under the same question returns arrays. That can actually be ***completely dynamic***. And that's what I suggest here, too. The query is actually rather simple:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY y ORDER BY tbl_id) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY y, tbl_id
   )
SELECT text 'y' AS col, array_agg (y) AS values
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1

UNION ALL
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT text 'x' || rn, array_agg (x)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY rn
ORDER  BY rn
);
```

Result:

```
col | values
----+--------
y   | {1,2,3}
x1  | {0,5,4}
x2  | {1,5,6}
x3  | {2,2,2}
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=331672cbf601f37f19a12899b3ccf7bd)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/16a01/1)</sub>

#### Explanation

- The CTE computes a row_number `rn` for each row (each `x`) per group of `y`. We are going to use it twice, hence the CTE.
- The 1st `SELECT` in the outer query generates the array of `y` values.
- The 2nd `SELECT` in the outer query generates all arrays of `x` values in order. Arrays can have different length.

Why the parentheses for `UNION ALL`? See:

- [Sum results of a few queries and then find top 5 in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528787/sum-results-of-a-few-queries-and-then-find-top-5-in-sql/8528920#8528920)