# In SQL how to select previous rows based on the current row values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I've a simple SQL table which looks like this-

```
CREATE TABLE msg (
    from_person character varying(10),
    from_location character varying(10),
    to_person character varying(10),
    to_location character varying(10),
    msglength integer,
    ts timestamp without time zone
);
```

[image: sample data]

I want to find out for each row in the table if a different 'from_person' and 'from_location' has interacted with the 'to_person' in the current row in last 3 minutes.

For example, in above table, for row # 4, other than mary from Mumbai (current row), nancy from NYC and bob from Barcelona has also sent a message to charlie in last 3 minutes so the count is 2.

Similarly, for row#2, other than bob from Barcelona (current row), only nancy from NYC has sent a message to charlie in ca (current row) so the count is 1

Example desired output-

```
0
1
0
2
```

I tried using window function but it seems that in frame clause I can specify rows count before and after but I can't specify a time itself.

Comment: It would be much easier if you provided the sample data as inserts.

Comment: When you say "last 3 minutes" do you mean the last 3 from the current time, or from the timestamp on the record?

Comment: @TimJasko I mean last 3 minutes from the record

Comment: In that case you should remove the `abs` from my answer, which currently goes 3 minutes in either direction.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you count 'nancy' for 'bob', but not vice versa. The two first rows of your result should be either `0, 0` or `1, 1`, but not `0,1`. Please provide data as text, never as image. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As is well known, every table in Postgres has a primary key. Or should have at least. It would be great if you had a primary key defining expected order of rows.

Example data:

```
create table msg (
    id int primary key,
    from_person text,
    to_person text,
    ts timestamp without time zone
);

insert into msg values
(1, 'nancy',   'charlie', '2016-02-01 01:00:00'),
(2, 'bob',     'charlie', '2016-02-01 01:00:00'),
(3, 'charlie', 'nancy',   '2016-02-01 01:00:01'),
(4, 'mary',    'charlie', '2016-02-01 01:02:00');
```

The query:

```
select m1.id, count(m2)
from msg m1
left join msg m2
on m2.id < m1.id
and m2.to_person = m1.to_person
and m2.ts >= m1.ts- '3m'::interval
group by 1
order by 1;

 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     0
  2 |     1
  3 |     0
  4 |     2
(4 rows)
```

In the lack of a primary key you can use the function `row_number()`, for example:

```
with msg_with_rn as (
    select *, row_number() over (order by ts, from_person desc) rn
    from msg
    )
select m1.id, count(m2)
from msg_with_rn m1
left join msg_with_rn m2
on m2.rn < m1.rn
and m2.to_person = m1.to_person
and m2.ts >= m1.ts- '3m'::interval
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Note that I have used `row_number() over (order by ts, from_person desc)` to get the sequence of rows as you have presented in the question. Of course, you should decide yourself how to resolve ambiguities arising from the same values of the column `ts` (as in the first two rows).

Comment: It would be incorrect to rely on the sort order of a surrogate PK like this. And `a different 'from_person' and 'from_location'` is not represented in the solution.

Comment: Thank you, I've added a few explanations.

Answer (score 1):

This should more or less do it. Depending on your requirements, you may need to modify the middle two conditions in the where clause:

```
select *,
   (select count(*) from msg m2
    where m2.to_person = m1.to_person
        and m2.from_person != m1.from_person
        and m2.from_location != m1.from_location
        and abs(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (m1.ts - m2.ts))) <= 3*60)
from msg m1
```

Comment: I am getting error- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 7: from msg ;
        ^
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: syntax error at or near "from"

Comment: Missed a closing `)`

Comment: thanks. I am now getting error- ERROR:  function sum() does not exist
LINE 2:    (select sum(*) from msg m2

Answer (score 1):

**Building on your *actual* question**, this would be a correct answer:

```
SELECT count(m2.to_person) AS ct_3min
FROM   msg m1
LEFT   JOIN msg m2
   ON   m2.to_person = m1.to_person
   AND (m2.from_person, m2.from_location) <> (m1.from_person, m1.from_location)
   AND  m2.ts <= m1.ts   -- including same timestamp (?)
   AND  m2.ts >= m1.ts - interval '3 min'
GROUP  BY m1.ctid
ORDER  BY m1.ctid;
```

Assuming `to_person`, `from_person` and `from_location` are all defined `NOT NULL`.

Returns:

```
1   -- !!
1
0
2
```

Note that the result is basically ***meaningless*** without additional columns, any unique combination of columns, ideally a PK. I return the rows in the current physical order - which can change any time without warning. There is no natural order of rows in a relational table. Without an unambiguous `ORDER BY` clause, the order of result rows is unreliable.

According to your definition the first two rows (according to your displayed order) need to have the same result: `1` - or `0` if you don't count same timestamp - `0` for one and `1` for the other would be incorrect according to your definition.

In the absence of any unique key, I am using the [`ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html) as poor-man's surrogate key. More:

- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)

You *should* still have a primary key defined in your table, but it's by no means compulsory. That's not the only dubious detail in your table layout. You should probably operate with `timestamp with time zone`, have some `NOT NULL` constraints and only `person_id` columns referencing a `person` table in a properly normalized design. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE msg (
   msg_id         serial PRIMARY KEY
 , from_person_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES person
 , to_person_id   integer NOT NULL REFERENCES person
 , msglength      integer
 , ts             timestamp with time zone
);
```

Either way, relying on a surrogate PK for the purpose of your query would be *plain wrong*. The "next" `msg_id` does not even have to have a later timestamp. In a multi-user database a sequence does not guarantee anything of the sort.