# Is the rows selected in the same order as we insert in postgres/oracle?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, select, sql-order-by, sql-insert

I have a multi million table , lets say table1 ,I created another table table2 using the statement :

```
Create table table2 as select column1, column2 from table1 order by column1 column2;
```

Is there any surety that when fetching datas from table2 , it is fetched in the sane order it was inserted?
For example :

```
SELECT column1,column2 from table2 limit 100000 offset 2000000;
```

should have the same result as

```
SELECT column1, column2 from table1 order by column1,column2 limit 100000 offset 2000000;
```

Is there any documentation from which i can confirm this?
Iam using both oracle as well as postgres.

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation

Comment: Relational table is a set. It has no any order, the only way to explicitly guarantee an order in SQL is to use `order by`. Just imagine partitioned table that is physically stored as different objects. What is the order of rows in it?