# Trigger to delete rows from related tables before deleting rows from actual table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, sql-delete

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION(
id varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
que_type numeric(1));

CREATE TABLE ESSAY(
que_id varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ans varchar(2000),
FOREIGN KEY (que_id) REFERENCES QUESTION (id));

CREATE TABLE TFFB(
que_id varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ans varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY (que_id) REFERENCES QUESTION (id));

CREATE TABLE MCQ(
que_id varchar(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ans varchar(200),
FOREIGN KEY (que_id) REFERENCES QUESTION (id));
```

and try to create trigger so that when I delete from the main table, it will delete related rows from other tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_question()
RETURNS trigger AS $delete_question$
DECLARE
    BEGIN
    IF ( (OLD).que_type = '1' ) THEN
       IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mcq WHERE person_id = (OLD).id) THEN
          DELETE FROM mcq WHERE que_id='(OLD).id';
       END IF;
    ELSIF ( (OLD).que_type = '2' OR OLD.que_type = '3' ) THEN
       IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tffb WHERE person_id = (OLD).id) THEN
          DELETE FROM tffb WHERE que_id='(OLD).id';
       END IF;
    ELSIF ( (OLD).que_type = '4' ) THEN
       IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM essay WHERE person_id = (OLD).id) THEN
          DELETE FROM essay WHERE que_id='(OLD).id';
       END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
    END;
    $delete_question$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER delete_question
    BEFORE DELETE ON question
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_question();
```

When I delete data from `question`, the row disappear for a while. But when I refresh, it still there.
I tried to put `RETURN OLD;` but it failed because of the constrain relation.
What is wrong with this?

Comment: What's wrong with using `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the foreign keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more advice on your trigger function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_question()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

CASE OLD.que_type
WHEN 1 THEN
    DELETE FROM mcq   WHERE que_id=OLD.id;
WHEN 2, 3 THEN
    DELETE FROM tffb  WHERE que_id=OLD.id;
WHEN 4 THEN
    DELETE FROM essay WHERE que_id=OLD.id;
-- ELSE
--      Do something?
END CASE;

RETURN OLD;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- Your check for existence with a `SELECT` statement doubles the cost. Just run the `DELETE`, if no matching row is found, nothing is deleted.
- Use a `CASE` statement here. Shorter, faster. Note that plpgsql `CASE` is slightly different from SQL `CASE` statement. For instance, you can list several cases at once.
- You don't need the `DECLARE` keyword, unless you actually declare variables.

#### Alternative design

You could avoid the problem altogether by [cascading deletes via foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), as [@a_horse mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035105/plpgsql-trigger-to-delete-object-on-related-table-before-delete-object-on-actual/20051513#comment29864955_20035105). My schema layout would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE question (
   question_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,que_type    int   -- this may be redundant as well
);

CREATE TABLE essay (
   que_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
              REFERNECES question(question_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                               ON DELETE CASCADE
  ,ans    text
);

...
```

About `serial`:
[Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

Answer (score 1):

i then try solve it again.... IT WORKS PERFECTLY. YEAY.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_question()
RETURNS trigger AS $delete_question$
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF ( OLD.que_type=1 ) THEN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mcq WHERE que_id=OLD.id) THEN
      DELETE FROM mcq WHERE que_id=OLD.id;
   END IF;
ELSIF ( OLD.que_type=2 OR OLD.que_type=3) THEN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tffb WHERE que_id=OLD.id) THEN
      DELETE FROM tffb WHERE que_id=OLD.id;
   END IF;
ELSIF ( OLD.que_type=4 ) THEN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM essay WHERE que_id=OLD.id) THEN
      DELETE FROM essay WHERE que_id=OLD.id;
   END IF;
END IF;
RETURN OLD;
END;
$delete_question$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_question
BEFORE DELETE ON question
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_question();
```

there is no `' '` on `OLD.id` or even  `(OLD).id` and use `RETURN OLD;`