# Syntax of creating sequence and auto increment fields in PostgreSQL for the given table

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, sequence, create-table

I am new in PostgreSQL. I'm trying to figure out the syntax for creating the following table.
I'm having difficulties in creating the sequence and the auto increment fields.

```
    Column    |         Type          |                      Modifiers
--------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id_numuser   | integer               | not null default nextval('id_numuser_seq'::regclass)
 username     | character varying(70) |
 completename | character varying(70) |
 id_cat       | integer               |
 email        | character varying(70) |
 password     | character varying(30) |
 active       | boolean               |
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_numuser)
    "taskuser_uniq" UNIQUE, btree (username)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "users_id_cat_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (id_cat) REFERENCES usercategories(id_numcat)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column. Details here:
[Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

The *complete* Script:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id_numuser   serial PRIMARY KEY
  ,username     character varying(70) UNIQUE
  ,completename character varying(70)
  ,id_cat       integer REFERENCES usercategories(id_numcat)
  ,email        character varying(70) 
  ,password     character varying(30) 
  ,active       boolean
);
```

You can use [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org) to get complete reverse-engineered SQL scripts for all objects.

Aside: I'd suggest to use just `text` instead of `varchar(n)`.

Comment: Thanks,,,,But I would like to know the full syntax for crating this table. This will help in creating other tables. Thanks again....

Comment: @user3001418: Added a full script.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ever in doubt about how to define something, `pg_dump` will help.

```
pg_dump -t 'users' --schema-only
```

will print a dump that shows the command(s) to create your `users` table.

It won't use shorthand like `SERIAL`, so it'll create the sequence then assign the sequence ownership and set the column default. So sometimes there's a shorter and simpler way than how `pg_dump` does it. The way `pg_dump` does it will always work, though.

In this case it produces (trimmed):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id_numuser integer NOT NULL,
    username character varying(70),
    completename character varying(70),
    id_cat integer,
    email character varying(70),
    password character varying(30),
    active boolean
);

CREATE SEQUENCE users_id_numuser_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO MINVALUE
NO MAXVALUE
CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_numuser_seq OWNED BY users.id_numuser;

ALTER TABLE ONLY users ALTER COLUMN id_numuser 
SET DEFAULT nextval('users_id_numuser_seq'::regclass);

ALTER TABLE ONLY users
ADD CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_numuser);

ALTER TABLE ONLY users
ADD CONSTRAINT users_username_key UNIQUE (username);

ALTER TABLE ONLY users
ADD CONSTRAINT users_id_cat_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_cat) REFERENCES usercategories(id_numcat);
```

So it's defining the sequence and all the constraints after creating the base table, not as part of it, and it's specifying a bunch of stuff that would usually be set by defaults.

The effect is the same and you can do things this way if you want. 
Stuff like `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` is basically just convenient shorthand. All that is covered well in [the documentation for `CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html), so once you know what you want you can generally figure out how to define it pretty easily. Most of the time, anything you can write in `ALTER TABLE ... ADD ...` can be written the same in `CREATE TABLE (...)`, eg:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY users
ADD CONSTRAINT users_id_cat_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_cat) REFERENCES usercategories(id_numcat);
```

can be done at create time with:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ....,
    CONSTRAINT users_id_cat_fkey FOREIGN KEY (id_cat) REFERENCES usercategories(id_numcat)
);
```

Additionally, for any column-specific `CONSTRAINT` there's usually a way to tack it on to the end of the column definition. In this case, you omit the `CONSTRAINT constraint_name` (it's generated) and the `FOREIGN KEY (id_cat)` (because the column is implied, you don't need to specify it), and write:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
     ....
     id_cat integer REFERENCES usercategories(id_numcat),
     ....
);
```

Once you know what to look for in the `CREATE TABLE` docs it's usually easy to find how to write what you want.