# Alter table add column default and execute the default for each row

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, plpgsql, alter-table, column-defaults

I am making a function that adds a id column to a given table, creates a sequence and fills the new columns value. The thing is that the column is created but now I need to fill it with `nextval()` of the created sequence (1,2,3,4,5...). I don't know how to specify that in the add column sentence.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_id(tabla character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE

BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT information_schema.columns.column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE information_schema.columns.table_name=tabla AND information_schema.columns.column_name='id')
THEN
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '|| tabla ||' ADD COLUMN id numeric(8,0)';

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname='seq_id_'||tabla) 
    THEN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE SEQUENCE seq_id_'||tabla||' INCREMENT 1  MINVALUE 1  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807  START 1 CACHE 1';
        EXECUTE 'GRANT ALL ON TABLE seq_id_'||tabla||' TO postgres';
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ONLY '||tabla||' ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval(''seq_id_'||tabla||'''::regclass)';
    END IF; 
END IF;

RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You need to update new `id` column, filling it with nextval? Sorted by what criteria?

Comment: sorted by no criteria, the first record first value, second record second value, third record third value..

Comment: There is no 'first' and 'second' words if there is no sorting criteria... Unordered select may return you values in any order it likes more.

Comment: If you don't care about order at all, just add `execute 'update ' || tabla || ' set id = nextval(''seq_id_'||tabla||'')';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function suffers from a number of series problems. Use this instead:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_id(_tbl text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$ 
DECLARE
   _seq text := _tbl || '_id_seq';
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM pg_namespace n
   JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
   JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid 
   WHERE  n.nspname = current_schema()  -- default to current schema
   AND    c.relname = _tbl
   AND    a.attname = 'id'
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped)
THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Column already exists!'; RETURN;
END IF;

IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM pg_namespace n
   JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
   WHERE  n.nspname = current_schema()  -- default to current schema
   AND    c.relname = _seq)
THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Sequence already exists!'; RETURN;
END IF; 

EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I.%I', current_schema(), _seq;    
EXECUTE format($$ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD COLUMN id numeric(8,0)
               DEFAULT nextval('%I'::regclass)$$  -- one statement!
               , current_schema(), _tbl, _seq);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- If you set the **column default in the same `ALTER TABLE` statement**, values are inserted **automatically**. Be aware that this makes a big difference in performance for big tables, since every row has to be updated, while adding a NULL column only needs a tiny change to the system catalog.
- You must define the **schema** to create objects in. If you want to default to the *current* schema, you still have to consider this in your queries to catalog (or information schema) tables. Table names are only unique in combination with the schema name.
  I use the [session information functions `current_schema()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE) to find out the current schema.
- You must safeguard against **SQL injection** when using dynamic SQL with user input. Details:
  [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)
- If the sequence already exists, do not use it! You might interfere wit existing objects.
- Normally, you do *not* need `EXECUTE GRANT ALL ON TABLE ... TO postgres`. If `postgres` is a superuser (default) the role has all rights anyway. You *might* want to make `postgres` the **owner**. That would make a difference.
- I am using the **system catalog** in both queries, while you use the information schema in one of them. I am generally not a fan of the information schema.Its bloated views are *slow*. The presented information adheres to a cross-database standard, but what's that good for when writing plpgsql functions, which are 100% not portable anyway?

### Superior alternative

- I would suggest *not* to use the **column name `id`**, which is an SQL anti-pattern. Use a proper descriptive name instead, like `tablename || '_id'`.
- What's the point of using `numeric(8,0)`? If you don't want fractional digits, why not use [**`integer`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html)? Simpler, smaller, faster.

Given that, you are much better off with a [**`serial` type**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517), making everything much simpler:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_create_id(_tbl text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$ 
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM pg_namespace n
   JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
   JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid 
   WHERE  n.nspname = current_schema()  -- default to current schema
   AND    c.relname = _tbl
   AND    a.attname = _tbl || '_id'     -- proper column name
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped)
THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Column already exists!';
ELSE
   EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I ADD COLUMN %I serial'
                 , current_schema(), _tbl, _tbl || '_id');
END IF;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```