# How to auto increment id with a character

Tags: postgresql, database-design, auto-increment

How do I auto-increment an ID of a member in my table together with a character with it
for example: `M_01`, `M_02`, `M_03`:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **Don't.**

Use a basic [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) column. You can always format the column on output.
A sensible table definition could look like this (added more suggestions):

```
CREATE TABLE company(
    company_id serial PRIMARY KEY
  , birth_year int    NOT NULL
  , company    text   NOT NULL
  , address    text
  , salary     int            -- in cents
);
```

Then:

```
SELECT to_char(companyid, '"M_"FM00000')  -- produces M_00001 etc.
FROM   company;
```