# First values in an auto increment trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, auto-increment

I am working with the following table in PostgreSQL 10.3:

```
CREATE TABLE s_etpta.tab1 (
  Number VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  id VARCHAR(8),
  CONSTRAINT i_tab1 PRIMARY KEY(Number)
)
```

I need to increment the column `id` by 1 with every insert. I can't alter the table because I'm not the owner so I have no other choice than to increment a `varchar` column.

The column is type `varchar` prefixed with zeros. How can I specify that I want to start with '00000001' if the table is empty? Because when I already have values in my table the trigger gets the last value and increment it for the next insert which is correct, but when my table is empty the id column stays empty since the trigger has no value to increment.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema."Num" (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
DECLARE    
BEGIN

NEW.id := lpad(CAST(CAST(max (id) AS INTEGER)+1 as varchar),8, '0') from 
schema.tab1;

return NEW;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Comment: Use `COALESCE`, but really you should be using a sequence, as this is not safe for concurrent transactions.

Comment: Please remember to always disclose your version of Postgres.

Comment: unfortunately I can't alter the tables because I'm not the owner so I have no other choice than to increment a varchar column. And I want the column to be updated on an insert in my app.

Comment: I tried using the sequences (New.id:=nextval('MySequence')) ( but I have an error "the relation does not exist" for my sequence. I'm using Sql Manager for PostgreSQL 5.9.3

Comment: The version of your client (Sql Manager) is hardly relevant for this. Your version of Postgres matters: `SELECT version();`

Comment: It's PostgreSQL 10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger design is unsafe and expensive trickery that can easily fail under concurrent write load. Don't use a trigger. Use a `serial` or `IDENTITY` column instead:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Don't use `text` (or `varchar`) for a `numeric` value.

Don't pad leading zeroes. You can format your numbers any way you like for *display* with `to_char()`:

- [How to auto increment id with a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892695/how-to-auto-increment-id-with-a-character/22975084#22975084)

In Postgres 10 or later your table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE s_etpta.tab1 (
  number numeric NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,         -- not VARCHAR(40)
  id     bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY   -- or just int?
);
```

No trigger.

Seems odd that `number` is the PK. Would seem like `id` should be. Maybe you do not need the `id` column in the table *at all*?

- [Gap-less sequence where multiple transactions with multiple tables are involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578014/gap-less-sequence-where-multiple-transactions-with-multiple-tables-are-involved/22578288#22578288)

If you need to get the underlying sequence in sync:

- [How to reset postgres' primary key sequence when it falls out of sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244243/how-to-reset-postgres-primary-key-sequence-when-it-falls-out-of-sync/23390399#23390399)
- [Postgres manually alter sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745051/postgres-manually-alter-sequence/8750984#8750984)

---

If you cannot fix your table, this trigger function works with the existing one (unreliably under concurrent write load):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.tab1_number_inc()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE    
BEGIN
   SELECT to_char(COALESCE(max(id)::int + 1, 0), 'FM00000000')
   FROM   schema.tab1
   INTO   NEW.id;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tab1_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON schema.tab1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.tab1_number_inc();
```

The `FM` modifier removes leading blanks from `to_char()` output:

- [Remove blank-padding from to_char() output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242202/remove-blank-padding-from-to-char-output/22242593#22242593)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.But like I said in my previous comment I'm not the owner and I can't alter the table (which would have been more safe) so I have not other choice thant to cast a varchar to an int and vice versa to insert it in my table. I'm ust looking for a way to force the insert to have a certain value for my id column.

Comment: @user3365621: I added a "working" function - for while you are stuck with your unfortunate table design.

Comment: @user3365621: And I added `COALESCE` to catch the case with an empty table - your initial question. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.