# How to display all rows based on column frequency PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do we output columns based on the count of customer and order products by alphabetical order? 
Given the following table

```
Customer      | Product 
------------------------
James Jones   | Shoes
James Jones   | Top
Jay Smith     | Bottom
Jones Jones   | Shoes
Jones Jones   | Top
Jones Jones   | Bottom
```

Output

```
Customer      | Product 
------------------------
Jones Jones   | Bottom
Jones Jones   | Shoes
Jones Jones   | Top
James Jones   | Shoes
James Jones   | Top
Jay Smith     | Bottom
```

Where Jones Jones is shown first as he has the highest amount of products and products are displayed in alphabetical order. This is then repeated for other customers based on product count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to add the count per customer with a window function in a subquery, and then order by that.

```sql
SELECT customer, product
FROM  (
   SELECT customer, product
        , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) AS ct
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub
ORDER  BY ct DESC, customer, product;
```

Since multiple customer may have the same number of products, add more `ORDER BY` expressions to get a deterministic sort order.

Comment: How would this code change if we wanted the Product order to stay the same?

Comment: @Ant: What product order? By some undeclared `id`? There is no natural order in a relational table.

Comment: For instance, in this question products were ordered by alphabetical order. However, what if you wanted products to be returned in the order before reordering by the Customer count.

For instance it would appear as this
Jones Jones -> Shoes, Top, Bottom

Comment: There was ***no*** order before. You have listed rows in a certain order, but there is no such order in a `SELECT` unless instructed by `ORDER BY`. Don't confuse a relational table with an spreadsheet. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22967310/939860

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery with `sum`:

```
select t1.* from t t1 
order by (select sum(case when t1.customer = t2.customer then 1 end) from t t2) desc, t1.product asc;
```

Comment: The correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` would scale terribly with  O(N³) due to the unrestricted self-join.