# How to backfill an incrementing id using alembic in postgres

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I have a flask app that is backed by a postgres database using flask-sqlalechmy. I've been using [miguel grinberg's flask migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to handle migrations, although I've come to realize that since it is a wrapper on top of alembic, I'm best served by asking questions framed in alembic.

The problem is that I have an association table that I forgot to add a unique id to.

Here is my class for the table with the new column. But I have some records in my database, so trying to run the default migration script of course gives me the "column cannot contain nullable values" error.

```py
class HouseTurns(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'house_turns'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) // the new column I want to add

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), primary_key=True)
    house_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("houses.id"), primary_key=True)
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("movies.id"), primary_key=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())

    user = db.relationship(User, lazy="joined")
    house = db.relationship(House, lazy="joined")
    movie = db.relationship(Movie, lazy="joined")
```

And here's the migration script generated by alembic

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('house_turns', sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_column('house_turns', 'id')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

I am really at a loss for how to write a migration that backfills the ids for the existing records with unique values. They don't necessarily need to be unique ids, just incrementing integers.

Answer (score 2):

In the `upgrade` method you need to alter the `add_column` statement so that the column is initially created with `nullable=True`, then you can backfill the column, and then alter the column back to `nullable=False`.

That is, this line:

`op.add_column('house_turns', sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False))`

becomes:

`op.add_column('house_turns', sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))`

You can then add statements to backfill your column. For example, looking at this SO question ['How to update with incrementing value'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23095247/2800058), would give you something along the following lines (untested):

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    # Make the id initially nullable
    op.add_column('house_turns', sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True))
    # create the temporary sequence - will be dropped at the end of this session
    op.execute('create temporary sequence sequence_house_turns')
    # set the start value of the sequence to 1
    op.execute("select setval('sequence_house_turns', 1")
    # update the existing rows
    op.execute('update house_turns set id=nextval('sequence_house_turns') where id is null')
    # Make the id required
    op.alter_column('house_turns', 'id', nullable=False)
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```