# Foreign key of serial type - ensure always populated manually

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have two tables: countries and regions.

```
CREATE TABLE Countries(
    id     SERIAL,
    name   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

CREATE TABLE Regions(
    id           SERIAL,
    countryId    SERIAL,
    name         VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id       ),
    FOREIGN KEY(countryId) REFERENCES Countries(id)
)
```

When I insert into regions, I would hope that if I fail to mention `countryId`, I would be stopped, however, `countryId` is automatically incremented. Is there any way I can be stopped automatically to make this insertion?

Following table where I set `countryID` as `SERIAL NOT NULL` doesn't solve the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE Pigeons(
    id           SERIAL,
    countryId    SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name         VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id       ),
    FOREIGN KEY(countryId) REFERENCES Countries(id)
)
```

The following solves the problem but I would think that it's technically incorrect because my serial could be bigger than 2^31, but int will never be >= 2^31.

```
CREATE TABLE Legions(
    id           SERIAL,
    countryId    INT NOT NULL,
    name         VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(id       ),
    FOREIGN KEY(countryId) REFERENCES Countries(id)
)
```

What's the right approach here?

Comment: [Serial Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html)  section Table 8-2. Numeric Types and 8.1.4. Serial Types

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the link. So SERIALs are indeed positive only, just that they are '31 bit(effectively)'. Great. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest:

```sql
CREATE TABLE country(
    country_id serial PRIMARY KEY
  , country    text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE region(
    region_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
  , country_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES country
  , region     text NOT NULL
);
```

Don't use CaMeL-case [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) if you can avoid it. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Use proper names. "id" or "name" are typically not descriptive enough (though "id" is a wide-spread anti-pattern used by various ORMs).

The underlying data type of a [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) is `integer`. Make the referencing column `integer`.
Due to the foreign key reference `region.country_id` can only hold values that are present in `country.country_id` (or `NULL`, unless defined `NOT NULL`). Your considerations about values > 2^31 are uncalled for.
In Postgres 10 or later consider `IDENTITY` columns instead. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Demonstrating short syntax for PK and FK definition (optional). [Read the manual on `CREATE TABLE`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)

Code example with more advice:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to educate me! Duly noted all the points. I read up the manual about identifiers, but while I can choose to not use camel case, I still want some sort of distinction in table name and column name which makes things somewhat easier to understand. I know I'm being unconventional, but I think in a structured way to an end. Are there any potential downsides?

Comment: @user247077: Downsides in what exactly?

Comment: Not following the convention.. ?

Comment: @user247077: I can't quite follow. `some sort of distinction in table name and column name`? What are you talking about? CaMeL case identifiers?

Comment: Yes, I would like table to be CamelCase and column to be camelCase, hence distinguishing between them on the basis of the case of first char.

Comment: @user247077: You *can* do that. Either just type it that way in your code, without double-quotes around the name. All identifiers are lower-cased internally, everything should work, but there are caveats, like with dynamic SQL. Or double-quote identifiers to force CaMeL-case names. I would advice to do neither - makes your life easier. But that's just my friendly advice.

Comment: Thanks. At this point I would continue with Camel case, but my stuff is pretty configurable, a string configures everything... so I can change later if there arises any issue.

Answer (score -1):

The right aproach is to read [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-numeric.html).

> The data types serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a
>   notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar
>   to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).
>   In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>       colname SERIAL ); is equivalent to specifying:
>
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
>
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>       colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq') );
>
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;

`SERIAL` is basically an autoincrementing integer. If your data is bigger than `int` you should use `bigint` and `countries` table should use `BIGSERIAL`.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't aware SERIAL isn't positive only. I could have sworn I read something to that effect.

Comment: @user247077: A default `serial` column is positive only. You can adapt it to insert negative numbers, too.