# Print the output of execution of DO anonymous block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have an anonymous `DO` block in a Postgres database like below:

```
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$ 
DECLARE
     FUNC_ID smallint;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO FUNC_ID FROM FUNCTION WHERE NAME = 'addition';
    IF FUNC_ID = 0 THEN 
       INSERT INTO FUNCTION ( ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, FUNCTION)
       values ((select (max(id)+1) from FUNCTION), 'subtraction'
              , 'calculate', 'catalog');
    END IF;

END;
$$;
```

If execute this block of code it gives output as only `DO`.

How to output the whole block of code to console?

Comment: Define "the output". Add an example of what you wish to get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a RAISE NOTICE statement

```
postgres=# DO $$BEGIN RAISE NOTICE 'Hello %', SESSION_USER; END; $$;
NOTICE:  Hello pavel
DO
```

See more in related [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).

Answer (score 5):

Your code is twisted in multiple ways. Use instead:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM function WHERE name = 'addition') THEN
      INSERT INTO function(id, name, description, function)
      SELECT max(id) + 1, 'subtraction', 'calculate', 'catalog'
      FROM   function;

      RAISE NOTICE 'Whatever'; -- see Pavel's answer
   END IF;
END
$do$;
```

You probably should have a [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) primary key, drawing the next value from a `SEQUENCE`. What you have is prone to race conditions and a typical anti-pattern.

Also I wouldn't use `function` as identifier even if that's allowed in Postgres. It's a [reserved word in the SQL standard](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

```
CREATE TABLE func
   func_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 , func text NOT NULL
 , description text
 , find_proper_name text)
);
```

Then your **whole statement** can be:

```
INSERT INTO func(func, description, find_proper_name)
SELECT 'subtraction', 'calculate', 'catalog'
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM func WHERE func = 'addition');
```

You don't need a `DO` statement *at all* here.