# Insert row into table with only a primary key field

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, auto-increment, sql-insert

Googling around told me to try this:

```
insert into Plan default values;
```

but I got:

```
null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

or this:

```
insert into Plan (id) values (null);
```

but I got the same thing.

The examples were for SQL: is there something different for PostgreSQL?

Table structure:

```
  create table Plan (
    id int4 not null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: Can you show your table structure please?!

Comment: "*The examples were for SQL*" - does not make sense. Postgres **is** using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `sequence` and set the default as `nextval` like so:

```
create sequence plan_sequence
start 100
increment 1
;

  create table plan (
    id int4 not null default nextval('plan_sequence'),
    primary key (id)
);
```

A sequence provides an auto-incrementing value. It is used for primary keys, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Your column does not accept NULL values (defined `not null`), and you did not define a default, either. So you *must* provide an `integer` value:

```
insert into plan (id) values (1235); -- any integer value
```

Most probably you really want a **`serial`** column, which draws a default value from a sequence:

- [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

Your table could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE plan (plan_id serial PRIMARY KEY);
```

An the `INSERT` could be:

```
INSERT INTO plan DEFAULT VALUES;
```