# Inserting a row in table that consist of only one auto increment PK column

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `VormerkListe` (
  `vormerkListeID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vormerkListeID`)
)
```

And I try to add a new column with this, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310462/insert-row-into-table-with-only-a-primary-key-field):

```
INSERT INTO VormerkListe DEFAULT VALUES;
```

But I get this error:

```
INSERT INTO VormerkListe DEFAULT VALUES Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT VALUES' at line 1  0.031 sec
```

Comment: That example was using Postgress  not MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a `null` value in the auto column. Something like this:

`INSERT INTO VormerkListe (vormerkListeID) VALUES(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
INSERT INTO VormerkListe () VALUES();
```

This looks funny, but I use it regularly. It means to use the default for every column in the table.