# How to autogenerate ID during sql INSERT?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, sql-insert, row-number

```
INSERT INTO table_having_pk SELECT * FROM table_without_pk;
```

Schema of both tables are the same, only the primary key constraints are not set for the `table_without_pk`.

Problem: during copy the entries of the 2nd table have `null` in ID, thus inserts into first table fails.

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: NULL-Value in Column ?id? violates Not-Null-Constraint
```

How can I let the 1st table autogenerate the IDs (just count them up) during insert?

Postgres 9.x

Inside my `@Entity` class the ID is generated as follows for the `table_having_pk`:

```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;
```

Comment: Version numbers for Postgres include the digit after the dot: http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *omit* the `id` column and it will be generated automatically for a [`serial`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) column.
You need to add a column list with all columns *except* the `id` column:

```
INSERT INTO table_having_pk (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM table_without_pk;
```

If your column does not have a default from a sequence (like a `serial` would), you can also drop the `id` column from *both* tables and:

```
INSERT INTO table_having_pk
SELECT * FROM table_without_pk;
```

Then add a `serial` column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_having_pk ADD COLUMN table_having_pk_id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

Numbers are auto-generated, so this will take a moment. Every row is rewritten.

**Or** you generate the numbers on the fly, if you don't want a `serial` (or can't have one):

```
INSERT INTO table_having_pk (id, col1, col2, ...)
SELECT row_number() OVER (), col1, col2, ...
FROM table_without_pk;
```

Comment: Would it have the same effect if I remove the `id` column from `table_without_pk` and then write again `insert into table_having_pk select *...`?

Comment: I cannot make the id colum `serial` as I have to maintain the hibernate auto generated sequence for not breaking the java code. Could I maybe `update` the `id` column within `table_without_pk` based on the sequence?

Comment: @membersound: I suspect that *is* implemented as `serial` in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table twpk(a text);

insert into twpk values('a'), ('b'), ('c');

create temporary sequence mysequence;

create table twpk2 as
select nextval('mysequence'), a from twpk;

select * from twpk2
```

Comment: Could you alsow explain your solution? Such answers are stronger, and more likely to get up-voted.