# Postgres triggers - adding old and new values

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers

I am trying to learn Postgres triggers, using some simple examples. I have created a simple table:

```
create table emp (empname text, salary integer, last_user text);
```

My goal is to replace the old salary with a new salary computed as the salary inserted (new) + the old salary. I could not get them to sum even when I did not put a condition (i.e. `empname` is the same)

Here is my code:

```
-- this table returns a new row instead of summing
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger
AS $emp_stamp$
BEGIN
new.salary = new.salary + old.salary ;
RETURN NEW; 
END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE  TRIGGER emp_stamp
BEFORE UPDATE on emp
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_stamp();
```

When I insert into the table, I get a new row added and no existing rows follow the formula:

```
INSERT INTO EMP VALUES('BR',39970,'BR')
```

I have also unsuccessfully tried the `UPDATE` command.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html) script says `BEFORE UPDATE`. So this trigger is not fired at all for `INSERT` commands.

Moreover, the same trigger function would raise an error for `INSERT` commands anyway because, obviously, there is no "old" version for newly inserted rows.

It should work just fine as is for `UPDATE`, though. I just cleaned it up a bit:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION emp_stamp()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.salary := NEW.salary + OLD.salary;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp
BEFORE UPDATE ON emp
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_stamp();
```

Just a proof of concept, I fail to see the point of adding up old an new value.

For starters, your table needs a proper `PRIMARY KEY`, a [**`serial`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517) column for instance (`empname` is hardly unique):

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  emp_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, empname text
, salary integer
, last_user text);
```

Then the `UPDATE` could work reliably:

```
UPDATE EMP
SET    salary = 39970
WHERE  emp_id = 123;
```

I still don't see how the mentioned trigger would make sense. You could **increase** an existing salary like this, no trigger involved:

```
UPDATE EMP
SET    salary = salary + 39970
WHERE  emp_id = 123;
```