# prepared statement inside function in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I can do the following in MySQL, but would like to know how to do the equivalent in PostgreSQL. I have to wrap the query in a string because the table name is variable (can't just run `CREATE TABLE`). This is all in a MySQL stored procedure / Postgres function.

```
    SET @createTable = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE ", table_name, "(
              id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              something varchar(255) NOT NULL");
    PREPARE createTableStmt FROM @createTable;
    EXECUTE createTableStmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE createTableStmt;
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this in Postgres?

Comment: It's called dynamic sql in Postgres. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run it *once*, just run the concatenated `CREATE TABLE` statement.

To encapsulate the functionality for repeated use with variable table name, use a plpgsql function with `EXECUTE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_my_table(_tbl text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I (id serial, something varchar(255) NOT NULL)', _tbl);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT create_my_table('foo_table');
```

To drop:

```
DROP create_my_table(text);
```

[There are many related answers here. Try a search.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D%20%5Bdynamic-sql%5D%20plpgsql%20execute)

Or if you only need it for the current session you can make it a temporary function that is dropped at the end of the session automatically:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.create_my_table(_tbl text) ...
```

Use a serial column to implement `AUTOINCREMENT` in Postgres:

- [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

You might want to make the column `PRIMARY KEY` as well.
And `varchar(255)` rarely makes sense. I would just use `text` instead:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496)

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks!