# ERROR: column "semester_id" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql, auto-increment, database-trigger

I created this PL/pgSQL trigger function in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.trigger31()
        RETURNS trigger
        LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
        COST 100
        VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
    AS $BODY$
    begin
        if(TG_OP='INSERT') then
            if(New.start_date>(select max(end_date) from "Semester") and New.end_date>New.start_date) then

                Insert Into "Semester" (semester_id,academic_year,academic_season,start_date,end_date,semester_status)
                values (New.semester_id=(select max(s.semester_id)+1 from "Semester" s):: integer,
                        new.academic_year= academic_year_trig(),
                        new.academic_season=academic_season_trig(),
                        new.start_date,new.end_date,
                        new.semester_status=semester_stat_trig()
                    );
                return NEW;
            else
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid start_date or end_date';
            end if;
        end if;
    end;
$BODY$;
```

Trying to execute it, I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "semester_id" is of type integer but expression is of type boolean
> LINE 2:    values (New.semester_id=(select max(s.semester_id)+1 from...
> ```

I am not sure why. I `cast` the expression of `New.semester_id` and I have
the same error. Also tried and this:

```
New.semester_id=(select max(s.semester_id):: integer +1 from "Semester" s)
```

and I still had the same error.

Comment: `Insert Into "Semester" (semester_id ,,,, values (New.semester_id=(select max(s.semester_id)+1 from "Semester" s)`  is prone to race condition why not using SERIAL on the semester_id column?

Comment: The `CREATE TRIGGER` statement should also be in the question. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: not i tried this.But it's ok mr Erwin solved my problem.Sorry guys next time i will try to expound better my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are mixing [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) and [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) syntax by mistake. It might work like this:

```
...
            INSERT INTO "Semester" (semester_id, academic_year, academic_season, start_date, end_date, semester_status)
            VALUES ((select max(s.semester_id) + 1 from "Semester" s),
                    academic_year_trig(),
                    academic_season_trig(),
                    new.start_date,
                    new.end_date,
                    semester_stat_trig()
                   );
...
```

But then I suspect you also misunderstood how triggers work. If that trigger function is for a trigger `ON INSERT` on table `"Semester"`, it would trigger an infinite loop - besides being nonsense, generally. Read the fine manual about [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/triggers.html) and [trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html).

All that aside, seems like you need to start by reading about `serial` and `IDENTITY` columns:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Comment: thank you very match it works now,but you are right.this trigger is an infinite loop :/