# Is it necessary to use all 3 foreign keys as primary key in an associative entity?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, constraints, primary-key

[Relational Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU3gw.png)

I want to break the many-many relationship between `SalesMan` and `Customer` with the new entity: `Sale`. 
I would like to use `idSalesMan` and `idCustomer` as primary key in `Sale` but `SalesMan` has a foreign key that will be in the `Sale` entity too. 
Do I need to use all 3 foreign keys as primary keys or are `idSalesMan` and `idCustomer` enough?

Here is how the script might look like (using Postgres):

```
CREATE TABLE Company(
    idCompany SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SalesMan(
    idSalesMan SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(45),
    wage DOUBLE NOT NULL,
    Company_idCompany INT REFERENCES Company ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(
    idCustomer SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Sale(
    SalesMan_idSalesMan INT REFERENCES SalesMan ON DELETE CASCADE,
    SalesMan_Company_idCompany INT REFERENCES Company ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Customer_idCustomer INT REFERENCES Customer ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (SalesMan_idSalesMan, Customer_idCustomer 
    /*,SalesMan_Company_idCompany?*/)
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the tile: **No**, not necessarily.

A PK like that would only even make sense if the combination of FK columns needs to be `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`. Neither has to be the case. In fact, enforcing uniqueness in this model would seem very odd. Customers are not allowed to buy from the same salesman twice? (Involving the same company?)

You would have additional columns to make each row in `Sale` unique. A `timestamp` comes to mind. You would have that, but it typically doesn't make sales unique. Two purchases might happen at the same time. With no reliable natural key, use a **surrogate PK** like a `serial` or an `IDENTITY` column.

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

I would do that in ***any*** case, even if the set of FK columns happens to be defined as `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`. I would create a `UNIQUE` constraint or index *additionally* (and `NOT NULL` constraints) where applicable. (Or at least a plain index for performance in most cases.) Maybe with the exception of very simple cases with just two small FK columns that can form the PK and the table is not itself referenced by FK constraints and unlikely to change later. For anything else, a surrogate PK is simpler, faster, more reliable and makes later changes easier.

Also, like [Mureinik explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50887058/939860), the FK column `SalesMan_Company_idCompany` is typically redundant and should be dropped: it's determined by the salesman. *Unless* your model allows sales between customers and salesmen involving an independent company somehow.

I would also reconsider the displayed naming conventions. More:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Thank you all. Is there any reason why MySql Workbench (tool I use for modeling) generates the SalesMan_Company_idCompany foreign key in Sale? it does it automatically and if you remove the key it deletes the relation.

Comment: @Javier: I don't know about MySQL Workbench, sorry. Maybe not the best tool to work with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

According to normalization best practices, you shouldn't even have a `SalesMan_Company_idCompany` column in `Sale`. The information about the company is held in the `SalesMan` table, and if you need it for a `Sale`, you should just join with the `SalesMan` table.