# How to store array of tables in Schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, many-to-many, database-normalization

So I am a student currently learning about PostgreSQL. I am trying to figure out the way, how to randomly seed data. I have 10M users and 100 stocks.

Currently my tables will look like:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  amount_of_stocks [][] array, -- this is just assumption
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE stock (
  stock_id INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  amount_per_stock INT,
  quantity INT
  PRIMARY KEY (stock_id)
);
```

How would I store 100 different stocks for each user?

Comment: Use 4 SPACE characters indent to auto-format your code snippets. I made that edit for you. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: Your title does not seem to fit the body of your Question.

Comment: Please fix your title to match the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a classical **many-to-many relationship**. Should not involve arrays at all. Assuming Postgres 10 or later, use something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE users (  -- "user" is a reserved word!
  user_id  int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, username text UNIQUE NOT NULL  -- or similar
);

CREATE TABLE stock (
  stock_id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, stock    text UNIQUE NOT NULL  -- or similar
);

CREATE TABLE user_stock (
  user_id  int REFERENCES users
, stock_id int REFERENCES stock
, amount   int NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, stock_id)
);
```

Detailed explanation:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)
- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

#### Seed

Postgres provides [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) to conveniently generate rows. [`random()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-RANDOM-TABLE) is instrumental to generate random numbers:

```
INSERT INTO users(username)
SELECT 'user_' || g
FROM   generate_series(1, 10000000) g; -- 10M (!) - try with just 10 first

INSERT INTO stock(stock)
SELECT 'stock_' || g
FROM   generate_series(1, 100) g;
```

Experiment with a small number of users first. 10M users * 100 stocks generates a billion rows. Takes some time and occupies some space.

> How would I store 100 different stocks for each user?

```
INSERT INTO user_stock
        (user_id,   stock_id, amount)
SELECT u.user_id, s.stock_id, ceil(random() * 1000)::int
FROM   users u, stock s;  -- cross join
```

Every user gets 100 *different* stocks - though everyone gets the same set in this basic example, you did not define more closely. I added a random amount per stock between 1 and 1000.

About the cross join to produce the Cartesian product:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167217/3684)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, really helpful

Comment: Hi Erwin what do you use to format your SQL statements? You do this by hand or using a tool?

Comment: @ErwinRooijakkers: I do it by hand, mostly. Seems tedious, but it helps me process, structure and understand complex queries a lot. I prefer this compact form over the often noisy format of various clients and frameworks. Actually, I like this special format  for `INSERT` (see update) to see which expression goes into which column at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,   
  stocks text[], 
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
```

Store a list of the primary keys in your Stock table, so you can easily look up their values with a select statement.

If you wanted to, you could make the array two-dimensional, and store the value.. but that violates some principle, I'm sure, as you already have a table for that purpose.