# How to test if an argument is null in plpgsql function body?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

My function code is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION INC(init_val)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $INVAL$

DECLARE CUR_VAL INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        CUR_VAL := (SELECT MAX(val_num) FROM values);
        CUR_VAL := CUR_VAL+init_val;
        INSERT INTO values VALUES (CUR_VAL);
        RETURN CUR_VAL;
    end;

    $INVAL$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I am trying to check if init_val is null. How do you do it?

Comment: IF init_val IS NULL then...

Comment: Or if you are doing this to substitute a value for NULL, then COALESCE(init_val, substitute_val).

Comment: Please tell me you are not using `select max()` to generate unique numbers. That is not going to work correctly with concurrent transactions

Comment: I am using select max() as to get the maximum value from the table and them increment it by one. number generation happens in CUR_VAL := CUR_VAL+init_val;

Comment: Two concurrent invocations of your function will calculate the same maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function exhibits multiple problems. And the description has contradictions.

This might do what you are looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_values_inc(_init_val int)
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$INVAL$
INSERT INTO values (val_num)
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(val_num), _init_val, 0) + 1
FROM   values
RETURNING val_num;
$INVAL$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_values_inc(7);
```

**But** that's just a proof of concept. I don't see the use case. The function cannot cope with concurrent writes on the table, as has been commented.

Consider a `serial` or `IDENTITY` column instead, both of which are designed not to break under concurrent write load. See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Aside: Avoid using SQL keywords like `values` as identifier. While this one is basically allowed in Postgres, it's [reserved in standard SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Use legal, lower-case, unquoted identifiers exclusively to make your life in Postgres easier. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)