# Copy data on parent and child table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[image]

I have two database tables. What I need to do is to copy specific data from one storage to another, but also keep the mapping to the photos. First part I can do easily writing

```
INSERT INTO item (storage_id, price, quantity, description, document_id)
SELECT 10, price, quantity, description, document_id
FROM item
WHERE quantity >= 10 AND price <= 100
```

but after that newly inserted items does not have photos. Note, that `document_id` field is unique for not copied items.

Comment: id id is an auto generated integer it changes with every new row you insert, besides  i am not sure what you try to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `id` columns are auto-generated surrogate primary keys, like a [`serial` or `IDENTITY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860) column.

Use a data-modifying CTE with `RETURNING` to make do with a single scan on each source table:

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT id, price, quantity, description, document_id
   FROM   item
   WHERE  quantity >= 10
   AND    price <= 100
   )
, ins_item AS (
   INSERT INTO item
         (storage_id, price, quantity, description, document_id)
   SELECT 10        , price, quantity, description, document_id
   FROM   sel
   RETURNING id, document_id  -- document_id is UNIQUE in this set!
   )
INSERT INTO item_photo
      (item_id,    date,    size)
SELECT ii.id  , ip.date, ip.size
FROM  ins_item   ii
JOIN  sel        s  USING (document_id)   -- link back to org item.id
JOIN  item_photo ip ON ip.item_id = s.id; -- join to org item.id
```

CTE `sel` reads all we need from table `items`.

CTE `ins_item` inserts into table item. The `RETURNING` clause returns  newly generated `id` values, together with the (unique!) `document_id`, so we can link back.

Finally, the outer `INSERT` inserts into `item_photo`. We can select matching rows after linking back to the original `item.id`.

Related:

- [Insert New Foreign Key Row for new Strings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81342/3684)

**But:**

> document_id field is unique for not copied items.

Does that guarantee we are dealing with unique `document_id` values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73685139/easy-in-excel-but-how-in-postgres Hi. wondering in that post do you have other way to solve it.

Comment: @jian: In fact, I think I do ...

Answer (score 0):

Given that `document_id` is the same in the two sets, we can used that to ensure that after the first copy, that all duplicate entries that have photos are copied across.

> **Note:** This is still a dirty hack, but it will work. Ideally with data synchronizations we make sure that there is a `reference` or `common` key in all the target tables. You could also use output parameters to capture the new `id` values or use a cursor or other looping constructs to process the records 1 by 1 and copy the photos at the same time instead of trying to update the photos *after* the initial copy stage.

This query will insert photos for items that *do **NOT*** have photos but another *item* with the *same* `document_id` *does* have photos.

```
INSERT INTO item_photo (item_id, "date", size)
SELECT "source_photo".item_id, "source_photo"."date", "source_photo". Size
FROM item "target_item"
INNER JOIN item "source_item" on "target_item".document_id = "source_item".document_id
INNER JOIN item_photo "source_photo" ON "source_item".id = "source_photo".item_id
WHERE "target_item".id <> "source_item".id
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id FROM item_photo WHERE item_id = "target_item".id)
  AND source_item.id IN (
                         SELECT MIN(p.item_id) as "item_id"
                         FROM item_photo p
                         INNER JOIN item i ON p.item_id = i.id
                         GROUP BY document_id
                        )
```