# Is it guaranteed that bigserial column is unique across all partitions of a partitioned table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, auto-increment, database-partitioning

I created the partitioned table in Postgres 15 with composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    date date,
    ..., 
    PRIMARY KEY(id, date)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (test_date);
```

I added several partitions like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_2020 PARTITION OF T for values from ('2020-01-01') to ('2021-01-01');
CREATE TABLE T_2021 PARTITION OF T for values from ('2021-01-01') to ('2022-01-01');
```

Question: is it guaranteed that the `id bigserial`  column will be unique across all partitions?

I see from metadata that there is just 1 sequence for table `T` created automatically for this `bigserial` column. There is no individual sequence per partition.

Does it mean that `id` column will be unique across all partitions?

Comment: If there's only one sequence, I can't see how this would not be the case

Comment: @Bergi: The sequence *assists* with unique default values, but it does not *guarantee* anything.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Right. I misunderstood the question to ask whether it is guaranteed that the sequence-generated values will be unique despite the sequence being used from multiple partitions (which they are, unless someone resets the sequence), not to ask whether the column values are contrained.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, subtle but important differences.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: is it guaranteed that the `id bigserial` column will be unique across all partitions?

Answer: **No.**

Quoting from the [chapter "Limitations" in the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE-LIMITATIONS)

> To create a unique or primary key constraint on a partitioned table,
> the partition keys must not include any expressions or function calls
> and the constraint's columns must include all of the partition key
> columns. This limitation exists because the **individual indexes
> making up the constraint can only directly enforce uniqueness within
> their own partitions**; therefore, the partition structure itself must
> guarantee that there are not duplicates in different partitions.

The `serial` column (or `bigserial` for that matter) draws values from a single `SEQUENCE`. While inserting default values, that results in unique `id` values across the whole partitioned table.

**However**, there is **no guarantee**. We can manually insert duplicates at will. Just like a `serial` column in a plain (non-partitioned) is no guarantee for uniqueness. The underlying `SEQUENCE` just helps to avoid unique violations. Only a `UNIQUE` index (directly, or indirectly as implementation detail of a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint) actually enforces distinct values. (With a loophole for `null` values - but PK columns are also `NOT NULL`.)

See demo in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WpUL7Yn2).

A more up-to-date `IDENTITY` column can do a better job. (Still no guarantee, though.) See:

- [Auto increment table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-table-column/9875517#9875517)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Yes, worth mentioning.